# Galois theory of ramified coverings vs classical Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory, galois-representations, fundamental-group, branched-covers

That's an exact copy of [my former MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673802/) I asked a couple of weeks ago and unfortunately not got the answer I was looking for.

The question adresses reuns' answer in this thread:  [Algebraic closure of $k((t))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565898/algebraic-closure-of-kt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the answer, reuns used a theory connecting classical Galois theory with Galois theory of ramified coverings. Unfortunately, he uses also some details which aren't clear to me, see below. Firstly, what I understoond:

In the setting of the linked thread we consider a finite Galois extension $L/\Bbb{C}(z)$. The theory says that one can associate to the field $L$ a unique connected Riemann surface $Y_L$ and a map $f_L: Y_L \to \Bbb{PC^1}$ which is a ramified cover over $\Bbb{PC^1}$ of degree $n=[L:\Bbb{C}(z)]$.

Ramified means that that there exist a  finite subset $S \subset \Bbb{PC^1}$ (= the "branch points")  such that the restricted map $Y_L \backslash  f_L^{-1}(S) \to \Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S$ is a $n$-cover known from basic topology.

We recover $L$ as the field of meromorphic functions on $Y_L$ (and $\Bbb{C}(z)$ " $\Bbb{PC^1}$).

The deepth of the theory gives a beautiful identification for Galois group  $$Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))= \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S,z_0)/Q$$

where $\pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1} \backslash S,z_0)$ is the fundamental group and the subgroup $Q \subset  \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)$ corresponds via classical covering theory to the cover $p:U_{\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S} \to Y_L \backslash  f_L^{-1}(S)$. Here $U_{\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S}$ is the universal cover of $\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S$. That's the background.

NOW THE TWO QUESTIONS:

reuns wrote:

> For $L/\Bbb{C}(z)$ a finite Galois extension then its elements are locally meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}$ minus a few branch points (the zeros of the discriminant of the minimal polynomials) and $Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$ consists of the analytic continuations along closed loops enclosing some of those branch points.
>
> Proof: with $\gamma_1(a),\ldots,\gamma_m(a)$ the analytic continuations of $a$ then the coefficients of $h(X)=\prod_{l=1}^m(X-\gamma_m(a))$ stay the same under analytic continuation, thus they are meromorphic on the Riemann sphere, ie. they are in $\Bbb{C}(z)$ so $h(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$.

**QUESTION #1:**  I learned this theory from Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups". In the construction there unfortunately wasn't explicitly explaned why the branch points of $f_L$ are the common zeros of the discriminants of minimal polynomials $F_i(z,T)$ of the generators $g_i \in L$ (in case $L= \Bbb{C}(z)(g)$ of $L$, while outside of the zeros/poles of the discriminants there are no branch points.

In spirit of this problem I'm looking forliterature explaning this construction of $Y_L$ from $L$ in that way there is *explicitly* pointed out why the branch points correspond to the common zeros of the discriminants $Disc(F_i(z,T))$ of minimal polynomials of the generators of $L$.

**QUESTION #2:**

How a $l \in \pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)$ represents
an element of the Galois group $Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$ explicitely?
Szmuely's book proves the isomorphism
$\pi_1(\Bbb{PC^1}\backslash S,z_0)/Q= Gal(L/\Bbb{C}(z))$
using category equivalences and unfortunately this proof not gives a good geometric
inside look what is going on there. In other words I "understand"
the proof step by step but have no visual intuition on this identification.

What we need is that such $l$ act as automorphism on
the meromorphic function from $L$ and fixes $\Bbb{C}(z)$.

Reuns explaned this identification as
" analytic continuations along closed loops enclosing some of
those branch points."

Unfortunately I can't imagine what he means by this analytic continuation and I would like to understand what he means here. ie wlog say our
$l$ is a class of such closed loop around a pranch point.
What/ which object is here "analytically continued along $l$"?
How does this construction work?. The object of our interest
is a meromorphic function $m \in L$ of $Y_L$.

How it can be "continued" by $l$? Isn't it already determined
on a dense open subset of $Y_L$ exept at it's poles.
Thus why and how it is continued along $l$? I not
understand it.